# How can I get the first element of this array in this var declaration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

If I do this with the element id `10_food_select`:

```
var id = $(sel).attr("id").split("_");
```

I get an array like this:

```
["10", "food", "select"]
```

What I want is for id = 10 (or whatever the first element is). I can get this later by writing `id[0]`, but how do I simply make id equal to the value of the first element of the split array, in that first var declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var id = $(sel).attr("id").split("_")[0];  // returns 10
```

This will give you the proper **id** straight away, without even doing

```
var id = $(sel).attr("id").split("_");   // returns ["10", "food", "select"] 
id = id[0];                              // returns "10"
```

Answer (score 4):

`[]` is pretty much just like any other operator.

```
var id = $(sel).attr("id").split("_")[0];
```

Since everybody seems to be offering regular expressions now, here’s mine:

```
var id = +/[^_]*/.exec($(sel).prop("id"));
```

If it’s going to be a number, you can do this too:

```
var id = parseInt($(sel).prop("id"), 10);
```

I think that pretty much covers the useful one-liners.

Comment: Too bad that you got the first answer, gave multiple options, and did not get the "accept".

Answer (score 2):

Another way though

```
var id = +($(sel).attr("id").replace(/_.+$/,''));
```

Comment: "replace everything after the first underline with nothing". Clever.

Comment: Glad someone noticed `:)`

Comment: "numberifying"? Is that even a word? Is that the job of the `+` in front of the expression? I'm always learning.

Comment: @Floris: Numberifying isn’t a word, but it is the job of the `+`, yes :) It’s an “implicit” cast to a number. Other tricks include bitwise operators that do nothing to cast to a 32-bit integer and `!!` to cast to a boolean.

Comment: @minitech thanks for the background. I always find languages with weak typing challenging - since I work in many different languages it is hard to keep track of these behaviors (e.g. when does `+` act as concatenation vs summation, etc). Oh for a nice set of type casting functions...

Comment: @Floris: Well, you can use `Number(x)`, `Boolean(x)`, and `String(x)`. It’s just that people… prefer not to. For no good reason, probably :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
var id = $(sel).attr("id").split("_")[0];
```

Comment: Thats the answer in my mind it doesnt mean I copied it. @Floris

Comment: That's fine - I wasn't accusing you of plagiarism. But if the goal is to provide the question with an answer, posting the same thing multiple times, while showing you know the answer too, doesn't make the site (as a repository of questions and answers) more usable/valuable.

Comment: Yes you are right but when i was posting the answer there wasn't a single answer that's the matter of time.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a regex replace if all you need is the first one from the split:

```
var id = sel.id.replace(/^([^_]+).*/, '$1')
```

Note: `$(sel).attr('id')` is not needed. `sel.id` is sufficient.